# What is the function of Xylem parenchyma?

Tags: botany

why xylem need parenchyma cells ihave read these cells are connected with xylem by plasmodesma i know that plasmodesma is to connect between cytoplasm of two cells and xylem is dead so what is the need of xylem parenchyma ?

Answer (score 3):

I would like to aswer your question. First definition, function is from this [web](https://www.biology-online.org/dictionary/Xylem_parenchyma):

> The xylem parenchyma is comprised of parenchyma cells. Parenchyma cells are the only living cells in the xylem. They have thin cell walls, large vacuoles, prominent nucleus, and protoplasts. They have differing shapes although they are usually cylindrical and lobed in form. In the trunks of woody plants, the xylem parenchyma cells are colourless and are believed to be involved chiefly in storing starch, oils, and other ergastic substances. The inclusions in xylem parenchyma cells may contain tanninferous compounds.

And from this [article](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/pce.12831):

> Xylem parenchyma cells in contact with xylem conduits are assumed to simultaneously generate the energy gradient (deposition of solutes in the form of sugars, ions or a combination of both) that allows water to flow into empty vessels/tracheids, and supply water for refilling (Zwieniecki & Holbrook, 2009). Regarding the first task, the initial research focus has been on finding the source of osmoticum through analysis of carbohydrates in the parenchyma cells and the role of phloem in the delivery of sugars to sustain refilling. Both enzymatic analysis and visualization techniques have demonstrated that starch levels in living parenchyma cells adjacent to xylem vessels decrease on a timescale coincident with embolism refilling (Bucci et al., 2003, Nardini et al., 2011a, Sakr et al., 2003, Salleo et al., 2009, Secchi & Zwieniecki, 2011).